# c++ operator doesn't match operand error

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. I am getting an error when I try to output the result of a string vector. I was hoping someone can why? the code for GenerateCombinations function is from https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/unique-combinations. I wrote the main() function. I am using VS community 2015.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


//*****Please include following header files***** /
// string
// vector
/***********************************************/

/*****Please use following namespaces*****/
// std
/*****************************************/

static vector<vector<string>> GenerateCombinations(vector<string> arr)
{
    vector<vector<string>> combinations;
    int length = arr.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << length); ++i)
    {
        vector<string> combination;
        int count = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < length; ++count)
        {
            if ((i & 1 << count) > 0)
                combination.push_back(arr[count]);
        }

        if (count > 0 && combination.size() > 0) {
            combinations.push_back(combination);
        }

    }

    return combinations;
}


int main() {
    vector<string> arr = { "How", "Are", "You" };
    vector<vector<string>> combinations = GenerateCombinations(arr);
    vector <string> ::iterator itr;

    for (itr = combinations.begin(); itr < combinations.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << *itr << endl;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What results do you expect, and what results do you get?

Comment: `combinations` is obviously a `vector<vector<string>>`. Therefore, its `begin()` would obviously be a `vector<vector<string>>::iterator`, but you are trying to assign it to a `vector<string>::iterator`, instead. This is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks Sam for your quick response. I am the changes as you suggested and still get an error on the cout << line

Comment: `#include <Vector>` should be `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Sam has pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395773/c-operator-doesnt-match-operand-error#comment79748797_46395773), you are attempting to assign a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator` from `combinations.begin()` to `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`, hence the mismatch.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to worry less about actual types, and use `auto`:

```
for (auto itr = combinations.begin(); itr < combinations.end(); ++itr)
```

Or more simply:

```
for (auto combination : combinations)
```

Here `combination` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, so you can't just print that, you need to iterate through that as well:

```
for (auto combination : combinations)
{
    for (auto c : combination)
    {
        std::cout << c << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: consider using `auto&` unless you a need a copy